# How to make database connection into moodle 1.9.19 and retrieve records using get_record()

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am using moodle 1.9.19+.

I want to connect my database and retrieve & listing table values using moodle how to do that.

I am trying get_record() function.

Please anyone help me

Comment: Are you trying to connect as a custom moodle page or simple connection via php PDO?